# Returning a vector by reference

Tags: c++, c++11

i have the following issue.

```
typedef std::pair<VertexT,CostT>  LocalEdgeT;
typedef std::vector<LocalEdgeT>   NeighborT;
typedef std::size_t                 VertexT;
typedef double                      CostT;

virtual const NeighborT& getNeighbors( VertexT v) const override   
    {
        std::vector<LocalEdgeT> neighbors;
        //here I'm adding elements, not important for the question
        return neighbors;
    }
```

I can not make the function return NeighborT without reference, because I have to use a function that's given to me from my university, that requires the reference for some reason.

But when I return it with the following call in main:

```
std::vector<NeighborT> test = Object.getNeighbors(arg);
```

It gives a segmentation fault, probably because I'm returning reference to a local variable. Any idea how I can fix it, that it still returns the vector by reference and it works with my function call in the main method?
Furthermore I have to compile with c++11 standard.

Some additional information:

I just put in "Object" because i thought it isn't that important for the question. Im my case the function getNeighbors is a member of a Graph class, which has a certain number of Vertices and a vector for all Edges from Vertex a to Vertex b. The function getNeighbors should now find to a given Vertex v all neighbors. To have a own vector for every Vertex in the class is (from my point of view) not recommended. 
I do have a map, where I save all Edges, with its double "CostT" to go that edge. 
Here is the full class.

```
typedef std::size_t                 VertexT;
typedef std::pair<VertexT,VertexT>  EdgeT;
typedef double                      CostT;
    class DistanceGraph
    {
  public:
    typedef std::pair<VertexT,CostT>  LocalEdgeT;
    typedef std::vector<LocalEdgeT>   NeighborT;

  protected:

    std::size_t vertexCount;

  public:
    DistanceGraph( int num_verts= 0)
      : vertexCount(num_verts) {}

    virtual ~DistanceGraph() {}

    std::size_t numVertices() const { return vertexCount; }


    virtual const NeighborT& getNeighbors( VertexT v) const = 0;


    virtual CostT estimatedCost( VertexT from, VertexT to) const = 0;

    virtual CostT cost( VertexT from, VertexT to) const = 0;
};

class CoordinateGraph : public DistanceGraph {
public:

    std::map<  EdgeT, CostT  > allEdges;
    std::vector < std::pair < double, double > > geometricPosition; 

    void setNumVertices( size_t);

    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in,CoordinateGraph& g);

    virtual const NeighborT& getNeighbors( VertexT v) const override   
    {
        std::vector<LocalEdgeT> neighbors;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < (*this).numVertices(); i++)
        {
            EdgeT edge = std::make_pair(v,i);
            if((*this).allEdges.find(edge) != (*this).allEdges.end())
            {
                neighbors.push_back( std::make_pair(i,(*this).allEdges.find(edge) -> second));
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

    virtual CostT cost( VertexT from, VertexT to) const override
    {
        EdgeT edge = std::make_pair(from,to);
        if((*this).allEdges.find(edge) != (*this).allEdges.end()) return (*this).allEdges.find(edge) -> second;
        else return 10000000;
    }
};
```

To clarify this again, I can NOT make the function getNeighbors return NeighborT. 
One solution I see, is to make the neighbors of every Vertex a classmember stored in a vector.
The above code obviously has a problem with the return of a local variable, when I call the function like above stated.

Comment: Have you tried moving the definitions of `VertexT` and `CostT` to before they are used in the definition for `LocalEdgeT`?

Comment: It seems `getNeighbors` is part of a class. Maybe the vector should be a member of that class so that you can return a reference to the member

Comment: You're returning a reference to a local variable (`neighbors`) that's freed before the function returns. Use after free is UB.

Comment: Just return `NeighborT`.

Comment: Have you posted all relevant code? What is `Object`?

Comment: @4386427 Yes I did. Since OP decided to return `const NeighborT &`, the function they talk about most probably has a parameter of type `const NeighborT &`. If so, simply returning `NeighborT` seems like the best choice.

Comment: @JonHarper sorry for the mistake, in my Code it's in the correct sequence!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat : I can not return only NeighborT, because I have to use test routines, where I do not have any insight and they can not handle NeighborT without reference for some reason. 
I added some information to the post regarding the other questions.

Comment: What the test routines declarations (not definitions) look like? Sorry, but I want to clarify: Have you actually tried to pass `NeighborT` without reference to them, or you just guessed it wouldn't work since those functions have parameters looking like `const NeighborT &ref`?

Comment: Your method is `virtual`, suggesting that member of a `class`. Then you can hold neighbors as a member variable. Or, post the whole class declaration, so people can help regarding the design.

Comment: The test routine is just called by Testname(Graph). I don't have the code of the testroutine at the moment. But with only NeighborT the test routine gets a segmentation fault, which is now solved by the thread_local keyword for some reason.

Comment: If you are required to return by reference, the variable must be "alive" when the function returns. That means the variable must be a) "a class member" or b) it must be "static or thread_local " (which is probably not what you want) or c) allocated with `new` (which would be a real bad design). I have a feeling that you ended up in this situation because of a wrong design choice in some code you didn't post.

Comment: It is good practice to pass the reference to the function and manipulate it there.

Comment: @4386427 I did add the the class now to the original post. 
One way would be to have a attribute `std::vector < std::vector<NeighborT> > localEdge` where `localEdge[0]` are the neighbors of Vertex 0 and so on. But for a big amount of Vertices that would be a lot of needed memory.

Comment: This question needs a [mcve]; the original poster has given us an almost certainly misunderstood set of constraints.  This has led to an incorrct answer to the OP's real problem.  The proper answer could be a mere misunderstanding of constraints, or returning a class-local variable, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you seem to have the hard requirement to return the vector of neighbors by reference, you basically have no choice and have to store it in your class.

just make a `std::map<VertexT, NeighborT>` class member to store them.

on call of `getNeighbors` check for a existing entry and return either the existing or create a new one and add it to the map.

Comment: I share your thoughts. That's the way I will approach the problem now.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is make `neighbors` thread local and clear it on each invocation of the function, that way, you get the same semantics of static without the expensive initialization, assuming you're not multi-threading of course.

```
virtual const NeighborT& getNeighbors( VertexT v) const override   
{
    thread_local std::vector<LocalEdgeT> neighbors;
    neighbors.clear();

    // stuff...

    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: This did work for the test routine and my part of the code! 
Can you give some explanation on what thread_local does? Does neighbors stay in storage for the whole duration of my programm, therefore it can only exist one "neighbors" vector at time?

Comment: @Darragh it means that the variable is local to a single thread. So every thread has its own copy of the variable (static means that every thread has the same variable). Yes, neighbors stays alive for the whole program, but not, there are N neighbors for N different threads that call your function.

Comment: @darr Please note, if someone "solves" this problem at a workplace like this, I'd tell them to find another soluton.  If tney insisted this was a good idea, I'd encourage them to seek employment elsewhere.  999/1000 timea a hack like this will come back and bite you.  The real problem here is probably the OP has misstated the constraints due to lack of understanding, and this is not the correct solution.